# Replacement of li po battery with li ion battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated, battery-chemistry, replacement

Is it possible to replace a battery for headphones? I would like to replace a 052030 li po battery with a Nokia BL-5C Lithium Ion battery. The li po battery is rated at 130 mAh with 3.7v. The Lithium Ion battery, on the other hand, is 1 Ah with 3.7v.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would be concerned more about the space

Comment: LiPo and Li-Ion don't always mean the same thing when used by different manufacturers. **Check** the charging info for the cells. My charger does LiPos to 4.2v, but Li-Ions to 4.1v. Just sayin'.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://learn.adafruit.com/li-ion-and-lipoly-batteries/overview) is a really great guide to the differences between LiPo and Li-ion battery chemistry. They are very similar but have important differences. You must always be careful when charging and discharging lithium batteries, because they can explode if done incorrectly.

The short answer is yes, you can do that because the voltage is the same and the capacity is larger. This means that the charger voltage will be correct and that the charging current will be lower than 1C, which is safe.

The downside is that it will take a long time to charge in comparison.

Comment: What are the differences between Li-ion and LiPo?? (Except for the phase (liquid vs solid) of the electrolyte.)

Comment: That's just it, the electrolyte. LiPo is actually Li-ion Polymer. The electrolyte means the cell can be made smaller, lighter and has a slightly higher energy density.

Comment: What are the important differences then?

Comment: Why will it take long time to charge? As far as I know li ion and li polymer require the same voltage to charge

Comment: @OskarSkog - theres a lot to that, best I direct you to an authoritive source: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/the_li_polymer_battery_substance_or_hype

Comment: @AbuBakar - the charging of Li-ion cells must be carefully controlled. There will be dedicated charging circuitry that will ensure the voltage and current are kept within limits, as otherwise the cell can become damaged. The original cell has a smaller capacity, so if the charger is a "1C" i.e 130mA charger then its output current will be limited. By swapping the cell, you have increased the capacity to 1Ah but the charger will still be providing constant current (130mA) for the smaller cell so it will be slower. If you changed the charger to provide 1C for the new battery it would provide 1A.

Comment: What if I use charger that provides bigger amount current? Will it damage circuit or anything?

Comment: Did you read the link I posted? It contains answers to this question: https://learn.adafruit.com/li-ion-and-lipoly-batteries/protection-circuitry